# Finding Exact Matches in Text Strings with Search

Tags: excel, search

I've included example screenshots and the forumlas bellow. I'm basically trying to run a list of Competitors against a list of searches. The competitor list is static and the searches list will grow and change overtime.

I'm finding it challenging to get consistent results with the search formula. It either is too loose (example A) or too strict (example B).

Is there a way to use the formula to exact match whole words in a text string? Or do I need to get sneaky with a VBA (something I'm not too familiar with). Or should I be doing this in another program?

Thanks!

**Example A**

[image]

So here, my formula works and says that someone searched containing avamere. However, It gives me a false positive on "roseville communities" because it has seville in roseville.

**Example A Formula:**
SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2:$C$5,B2)))>0

**Example B**

So I tried to normalize the competitors with spaces:

[image: image.png]
Now they're all false.

**Example B Formula:**
SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&$C$10:$C$13&" ",B10)))>0

Comment: add the spaces to `B10` also: `" "&B10&" "`

Comment: So simple. Thank you! That worked.